# RxNetty reuse the connection

Tags: java, rx-java, netty, netflix-ribbon

I want to use Netflix-Ribbon as TCP client load balancer without Spring Cloud,and i write test code.

```
public class App  implements Runnable
{
    public static String msg = "hello world";
    public BaseLoadBalancer lb;
    public RxClient<ByteBuf, ByteBuf >  client;
    public Server echo;

    App(){
        lb = new BaseLoadBalancer();
        echo = new Server("localhost", 8000);
        lb.setServersList(Lists.newArrayList(echo));
        DefaultClientConfigImpl impl = DefaultClientConfigImpl.getClientConfigWithDefaultValues();
        client = RibbonTransport.newTcpClient(lb, impl);
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        for( int i = 40; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new App());
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread is finished");
    }
    public String sendAndRecvByRibbon(final String data) 
    {
        String response = "";
        try {
            response = client.connect().flatMap(new Func1<ObservableConnection<ByteBuf, ByteBuf>,
                    Observable<ByteBuf>>() {
                public Observable<ByteBuf> call(ObservableConnection<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> connection) {

                    connection.writeStringAndFlush(data);
                    return connection.getInput();
                }
            }).timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).retry(1).take(1)
                    .map(new Func1<ByteBuf, String>() {
                        public String call(ByteBuf ByteBuf) {
                            return ByteBuf.toString(Charset.defaultCharset());
                        }
                    })
                    .toBlocking()
                    .first();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(((LoadBalancingRxClientWithPoolOptions) client).getMaxConcurrentRequests());
            System.out.println(lb.getLoadBalancerStats());
        }
        return response;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            sendAndRecvByRibbon(msg);
        }
    }

}
```

i find it will create a new socket everytime i call`sendAndRecvByRibbon` even though the `poolEnabled` is setting to true. So,it confuse me,i miss something?
and there are no option to configure the size of the pool,but hava a `PoolMaxThreads` and `MaxConnectionsPerHost`.

My question is how to use a connection pool in my simple code, and what's wrong with my `sendAndRecvByRibbon`,it open a socket then use it only once,how can i reuse the connection?thanks for your time.

the server is just a simple echo server writing in pyhton3,i comment out`conn.close()` because i want to use long connection.

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import socketserver
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        conn = self.request
        while True:
            client_data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not client_data:
                time.sleep(5)
            conn.sendall(client_data)
#            conn.close()

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8000
    server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    ip, port = server.server_address
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    server.serve_forever()
```

and the pom of mevan,i just add two dependency in IED's auto generated POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>ribbon</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

the code for printing src_port

```
@Sharable
public class InHandle extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(ctx.channel().localAddress());
        super.channelRead(ctx, msg);
    }
}

public class Pipeline implements PipelineConfigurator<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> {
    public InHandle handler;
    Pipeline() {
        handler = new InHandle();
    }
    public void configureNewPipeline(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
        pipeline.addFirst(handler);
    }
}
```

and change the `client = RibbonTransport.newTcpClient(lb, impl);`to `Pipeline pipe = new Pipeline();client = RibbonTransport.newTcpClient(lb, pipe, impl, new DefaultLoadBalancerRetryHandler(impl));`

Answer (score 2):

So, your `App()` constructor does the initialization of lb/client/etc.

Then you're starting 40 different threads with 40 different RxClient instances (each instance has own pool by default) by calling `new App()` in the first for loop. To make things clear - the way you spawn multiple RxClient instances here does not allow them to share any common pool. Try to use one RxClient instance instead.

What if you change your main method like below, does it stop creating extra sockets?

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
    {
        App app = new App() // Create things just once
        for( int i = 40; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(()->app.run()); // pass the run()
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread is finished");
    }
```

If above does not help fully (at least it will reduce created sockets count in 40 times) - can you please clarify how exactly do you determine that:

> i find it will create a new socket everytime i call sendAndRecvByRibbon

and what are your measurements after you update constructor with this line:

```
    DefaultClientConfigImpl impl = DefaultClientConfigImpl.getClientConfigWithDefaultValues();
    impl.set(CommonClientConfigKey.PoolMaxThreads,1); //Add this one and test
```

**Update**

Yes, looking at the `sendAndRecvByRibbon` it seems that it lacks marking the [PooledConnection](https://github.com/allenxwang/RxNetty-1/blob/1bd025c21ec258706a1d93980a5852806070082b/rx-netty/src/main/java/io/reactivex/netty/client/PooledConnection.java#L151) as [no longer acquired](https://github.com/allenxwang/RxNetty-1/blob/1bd025c21ec258706a1d93980a5852806070082b/rx-netty/src/main/java/io/reactivex/netty/client/PooledConnection.java#L78) by calling `close` once you don't expect any further reads from it.

As long as you expect the only single read event, just change this line

```
connection.getInput()
```

to the

```
return connection.getInput().zipWith(Observable.just(connection), new Func2<ByteBuf, ObservableConnection<ByteBuf, ByteBuf>, ByteBuf>() {
                        @Override
                        public ByteBuf call(ByteBuf byteBuf, ObservableConnection<ByteBuf, ByteBuf> conn) {
                            conn.close();
                            return byteBuf; 
                        }
                    });
```

Note, that if you'd design more complex protocol over TCP, then input bytebuf can be analyzed for your specific 'end of communication' sign which indicates the connection can be returned to the pool.

Comment: same as before,both`new Thread(()->app.run())`and set `PoolMaxThreads`to 1 or 2000.For your question,you can print the port in the server or client to find it,a socket is determined by (src_ip,src_port,dest_ip,dest_port).

Comment: @obgnaw could you please describe exact method you use to print src port? And update you question with that pice of code?

Comment: add it and i believe the example is runalbe.